# javascript slideshow links on the same page

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I just copied JavaScript code from Google, and I don't know how to make a hyperlink that will be opened on the current page.

Here's the code which I inserted into the `<head>` section of my page.

```
var slideimages = new Array()
var slidelinks = new Array()

function slideshowimages() {
    for (i = 0; i < slideshowimages.arguments.length; i++) {
        slideimages[i] = new Image()
        slideimages[i].src = slideshowimages.arguments[i]
    }
}

function slideshowlinks() {
    for (i = 0; i < slideshowlinks.arguments.length; i++)
    slidelinks[i] = slideshowlinks.arguments[i]
}

function gotoshow() {
    if (!window.winslide || winslide.closed) winslide = window.open(slidelinks[whichlink])
    else winslide.location = slidelinks[whichlink]
    winslide.focus()
}
```

Here's the code I inserted into the body section:

```
<script>
<!--

slideshowimages("main.PNG", "mainhover.PNG")
slideshowlinks('index.php', '_self')

//configure the speed of the slideshow, in miliseconds

var slideshowspeed = 2500

var whichlink = 0
var whichimage = 0

function slideit() {
    if (!document.images) return
    document.images.slide.src = slideimages[whichimage].src
    whichlink = whichimage
    if (whichimage < slideimages.length - 1) whichimage++
    else whichimage = 0
    setTimeout("slideit()", slideshowspeed)
}
slideit()
slideit()

//-->
</script>
```

Everytime I click on the image, the index.php page always appears on the new tab,
is there an easy way, so that the index.php page can be opened on the same page?
I know nothing about JavaScript.

Comment: You could have the page dynamically switching content - but that would also be possible using PHP partials. Can you post some HTML or put this in a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the HTML will help understand the issue, but this code

```
if (!window.winslide || winslide.closed) winslide = window.open(slidelinks[whichlink])
else winslide.location = slidelinks[whichlink]
winslide.focus()
```

basically tells that if this is the first time you run it, then open a new window (`window.open(slidelinks[whichlink]`) which Chrome for example will use to open a new tab

Else if it's already created, change that window's location to the slide URL (`else winslide.location = slidelinks[whichlink]` e.g it's as designed to operate in a new window

to change it, you'll need to replace `window.open` with something that will operate on an iframe or something.

I'm not sure what is the purpose of opening a new window, but this is what the code does

On a side note, I'm not sure you found the best piece of code to run HTML based slides, If you want modern slides, I would try something like http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/